# C# Serilog - ApplicationInsights - ASP.NET Core 6 - Own Exception logging with ILogger

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-6.0, azure-application-insights, serilog

How can i set ApplicationInsights to send Ilogger _logger messages.
Now i see every log at Console and in files, but in azure i don't see my own Logs.
I tried a lot of things and maybe the information is here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-monitoring
But i don't find it. :(

Thanks for helping.

In Program.cs:

```
var _logger = new LoggerConfiguration().CreateBootstrapLogger();

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Host.UseSerilog((context, services, loggerConfiguration) => loggerConfiguration
               .ReadFrom
               .Configuration(builder.Configuration)
               .Enrich
               .FromLogContext());
Bootstrap.ConfigureServices(builder.Services, builder.Configuration, builder.Environment);

var app = builder.Build();
Bootstrap.ConfigureWebApp(app);

app.Run();
```

In appsettings.json:

```
  "Serilog": {
    "Using": [
      "Serilog.Sinks.Console",
      "Serilog.Sinks.File",
      "Serilog.Sinks.ApplicationInsights"
    ],
    "MinimumLevel": {
      "Default": "Debug"
    },
    "Enrich": [ "FromLogContext", "WithMachineName", "WithProcessId", "WithThreadId" ],
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "Console"
      },
      {
        "Name": "File",
        "Args": {
          "Path": "../Logs/MyLog-.json",
          "RollingInterval": "Day",
          "formatter": "Serilog.Formatting.Json.JsonFormatter, Serilog"
        }
      },
      {
        "Name": "File",
        "Args": {
          "Path": "../Logs/MyLog-.log",
          "RollingInterval": "Day",
          //"OutputTemplate": "[({Component}|{MachineName}|{ThreadId}) {Timestamp:G} [{Level:u3}]{Message:lj}{NewLine}{Exception} ]"
        }
      },
      {
        "Name": "ApplicationInsights",
        "Args": {
          "ConnectionString": "[MyCONNECTIONSTRING]",
          "telemetryConverter": "Serilog.Sinks.ApplicationInsights.TelemetryConverters.TraceTelemetryConverter, Serilog.Sinks.ApplicationInsights"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
```

Comment: In [serilog-sinks-applicationinsights documentation](https://github.com/serilog-contrib/serilog-sinks-applicationinsights) the connection string property is in lower camel case "connectionString". I don't know if it is case sensitive but try to change it in your config file.

Comment: I get logs so it works. I dont get every log, which i log with ILogger interface. In file i get these logs. In azure i don's see my own logs :(

Comment: Which log level are you accepting in AppI? 
if you are allowing only warning and error, but logging information.... That is why..

Try to hardcode "_logger.Error("Hello world");
as the first line after your app has initialized.

Comment: The default logging is Information

Comment: Actually in Visual Studio when i running the application i see i send logs for Application Insights but i didn't see my own logs... 
In file, in console and in output windows i see the logs. But in Azure i dont see,

Comment: did you check the connection string ? it can be associated with key that can read application insight only. it depends on rights... 
you can work with managed identity rather than connection string ......

Comment: Actually i get my logs.... My logs are delayed some hours.....
THanks for helping!

Comment: it seems like azure needs some time to process the logs.